# What is the "Rails Way" to re-associate posts or other objects attached to a user when said user is deleted?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, associations, one-to-many, model-associations

I am implementing a system where when a user deletes his/her account posts they have made will be re-associated to an anonymous account so they can still be displayed for other users of my site.

My site has a `one_to_many` association between users and posts.

There doesn't seem to be a matching option under `dependent: _______` as can be seen here
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many-label-Options

What I have done (and it is working) is added the following code to my destroy action inside of my user controller

```
    user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
    admin_id = User.find_by(email: 'admin_account@gmail.com').id
    user.posts.each do |post|
      post.user_id = admin_id
      post.save
    end
    user.destroy
```

I figured that this is likely a common enough desire to have a more standard, "best practice" or "Railsy" way of accomplishing it, if there is what is it?

Comment: is `re-associated to an anonymous account` a must? if not, you could set `dependent: :nullify` and still have the post available

Comment: Yeah, I want it attached to a user still otherwise I would have gone with that exact solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dependent` attribute doesn't have an option for what you are looking for. You can, however, use the `before_destroy` callback to modify the associated model.

```
before_destroy :modify_association

def modify_association
  associated_model.update(...)
end
```

You can read more about it [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.0/active_record_callbacks.html#destroying-an-object)